# Oracle Apex 19 - Select null value from a date picker

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 19. For a Date page element in a form region, when the user updates the values, I have to let them clear the Date value manually from the Date Picker when it is set earlier. I know that Dynamic Action can do the job. I was looking for a direct Date Picker property.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like it can be done with a Dynamic Action, but needs some clarification.  Are you saying when another field is change, the Date field needs to be set to null? or when the Date field changes, then another field is set to null?

Comment: Thank you EJ Egyed. I edited the question to clarify.